# Samsung Smart TV Trigger remote key by click

Tags: triggers, youtube-javascript-api, samsung-smart-tv

i have an Samsung Smart TV app and i have a problem with mouse. the problem: i have two scenes. in first scene are show ten news. on pressing enter it shows the second scene with detailed news and a youtube video. when i do that with remote control, everything works just fine. when i do the same with mouse the youtube player is not working. i rechecked 100 times that on click i execute the same commands as on enter. the console dont give me any errors, and everything is executing exept the youtube player. i testet it on emulator and on TV and the problem is the same. so my question is: can i call a function on click that triggers (simulates) a remote control key? thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**SOLUTION**

to trigger a remote control key use the function:
`sf.scene.get('Main').handleKeyDown(sf.key.ENTER);`
but this doesnt solve my problem.
i solved it by changing youtube video player version from 3 to 2
ex: `http://www.youtube.com/apiplayer?&enablejsapi=1&version=2`
it seems tha the TV have some issues with newer versions of flash..